pyqt5 layout.replaceWidget kills setTextInteractionFlags of unrelated QLabel?
Consider the following example, based on the example from https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt-dialogs/ , where I want to have a custom QDialog class, where text in the label is selectable, and where I can control the buttons at instantiation:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class CustomDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("HELLO!")

        self.QBtn = QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel

        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(self.QBtn)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.message = QLabel("Something happened, is that OK?")
        self.message.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse | Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.message)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    @classmethod # SO:141545; call w. QtawAnimIconRszMsgBoxDialog.fromqmb(...)
    def fromstr(cls, msg=None, buttons=None, parent=None):
        instance = cls(parent)
        if buttons:
            old_button_box = instance.buttonBox
            instance.QBtn = buttons
            instance.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(instance.QBtn)
            instance.layout.replaceWidget(old_button_box, instance.buttonBox) # MUST have this; but this also kills setTextInteractionFlags!
            old_button_box.clear() # "Clears the button box, deleting all buttons within it"
        if msg:
            instance.message.setText(msg)
        return instance

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        button = QPushButton("Press me for a dialog!")
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def button_clicked(self, s):
        print("click", s)

        #dlg = CustomDialog(self)
        #dlg = CustomDialog.fromstr("Hello there!", parent=self) # setTextInteractionFlags OK
        dlg = CustomDialog.fromstr("Hello there!", QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, self) # kills setTextInteractionFlags
        if dlg.exec():
            print("Success!")
        else:
            print("Cancel!")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()

If you run the code as is, click on "Press me ...":

... and then try to select the "Hello there" from the dialog with the mouse, you will not be able to, in spite of self.message.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse | Qt.TextSelectableByMouse).
But, if you avoid the re-instantiation of buttons by toggling the commenting of these lines:
# ...
        dlg = CustomDialog.fromstr("Hello there!", parent=self) # setTextInteractionFlags OK
        #dlg = CustomDialog.fromstr("Hello there!", QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, self) # kills setTextInteractionFlags
# ...

... then the "Hello there!" text WILL be selectable with the mouse.
I've (hopefully correctly) reduced this problem to the line instance.layout.replaceWidget(old_button_box, instance.buttonBox). So, why does replaceWidget of an unrelated widget in the layout kill the textInteractionFlags on the QLabel?
And is there a way to allow for button replacement of the QDialog correctly, either by continuing to use .replaceWidget but not kill the textInteractionFlags of the QLabel - or by using some other approach?

EDIT: found a workaround - considering that I want to change the buttonBox, which is "last" in the layout, then instead of replaceWidget, I can just use removeWidget and addWidget:
# ...
            # retitem = instance.layout.replaceWidget(old_button_box, instance.buttonBox) # MUST have this; but this also kills setTextInteractionFlags!
            instance.layout.removeWidget(old_button_box)
            instance.layout.addWidget(instance.buttonBox)
            old_button_box.clear() # "Clears the button box, deleting all buttons within it"
            del old_button_box
        if msg:
# ...

... and then CustomDialog.fromstr works fine with a button specification (in that the label text remains selectable, as it was supposed to).
But still, I'd like to know - why is .replaceWidget not working in this case, and what could one do to use that instead (in case one needs to do a similar replacement, but the widget is not the "last" in layout, so remove/add is not applicable)?

tl;dr
Calling replaceWidget() is insufficient: you should also properly delete or, at least, hide it the old widget.
The more appropriate solution, though, is to replace the buttons of the current button box, using setStandardButtons().
Explanation
The problem isn't related to the text interaction flags (which remain unchanged). What you see is a symptom of the real problem: you are not deleting the old button box instance.
When you call replaceWidget(), the widget is not deleted, it's layout item is actually switched with another one containing the new one, but the old widget is still there: its parent is unchanged, which is why you probably tried to call clear() in order to delete the buttons, but that's still insufficient.
When a widget is firstly created, it always has a default size: when created with a parent, its size is 100x30, while no-parent widgets (potentially, top level windows) always default to 640x480. It's only when it's finally shown and its layout (if any) activated that its size may eventually change.
In your code, the instance is created but the original button box is immediately "replaced" (but only in the layout) and cleared of its contents.
This means that its internal layout is never activated, because it has no children, and no parent layout is managing it anymore, so it retains its original 640x480 size.
The reality is that it is still there, you just cannot see it because it's empty and it has no background.
Just add the following to the end of the __init__:
        self.buttonBox.setStyleSheet('background: green;')
        self.buttonBox.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground)

The result will then be the following:

The new button box is visible and can be used because it's added after (and, therefore, above), but the QLabel was already there, and inserted to the layout before the old button box, so it's hidden by it not only visually, but also for mouse events.
To clarify, here is the window resized to 800x600, showing the green area defining the button box at 640x480:

And here is when we enlarge the window enough to finally show the label outside of the old button box margins (the label is centered in its layout item), which makes selection now possible:

The following is a list of acceptable possible solutions, that are not completely appropriate, but can provide a better understanding about how layout management works:

explicitly hide() (or setVisible(False)) on the old button box: invisible widgets are obviously transparent to mouse events (even if they could retain their geometry in a layout using a proper QSizePolicy) so even a widget that is theoretically stacked before a "hidden" one can receive those events;
set the Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents on the old button box: similar to the above;
call raise_() on the message QLabel at any time after setLayout() (including the class method);
add the label after the buttonbox, but using insertWidget(0, self.message), so that it's stacked above (again, after calling setLayout());
as usual, creating a layout with the widget in its constructor automatically installs itself on the given widget (no need for setLayout()), so the last two above can be achieved even right after doing self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self);

The proper solution, though, would normally be to call deleteLater() on the old button box; unfortunately this doesn't always work as expected: the problem comes from the QEventLoop that QDialog runs when calling exec() (one of the reasons for which that function is normally discouraged in the documentation). Due to the complex interactions within nested event loops, the deletion request event will not be managed immediately, because it was called in the outer loop (that of the QApplication).
Another alternative, a bit more accurate than those listed above, could then be to reparent the button box to None, since setParent() always hides the widget:
old_button_box.setParent(None)

Garbage collection (united with the null parent) will take care of object deletion, and in this specific case it actually works, as opposed to deleteLater(): the widget will be actually destroyed as soon as fromstr() returns.
The correct solution
In reality, as interesting as it may be, all this doesn't really matter that much: it makes little sense to create a new button box to replace another, especially if we then forget to connect again its signals.
Just call setStandardButtons() with the new buttons, so that the old ones will be automatically deleted (similarly to clear()) and then replaced with the new ones:
    def fromstr(cls, msg=None, buttons=None, parent=None):
        instance = cls(parent)
        if buttons:
            instance.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(buttons)
        ...

